# How to get request by type?

Tags: node.js, json, api, get, get-request

I'm kinda stuck on this one. I have a JSON file that is like this:

```
[
    {
     id: 123
     content: Hello my name is abc
     type: commentary
    }
]
```

I do know that you can call an api using an ID as such. Example: ```www.helloworld.com/get/123, I'll display the content.

```
router.get('/get/:id', async (req,res) => {
    const q_id = await Excuse.findById({_id: req.params.id})
    res.json(q_id)
```

What I'm stuck with is, how do I get the api using the type? I tried to stringify but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly, but maybe you are talking about a query.

```
GET /get/:id?type=some-type
```

The route would be like

```js
router.get('/get/:id', async (req,res) => {
    const type = req.query.type; // that is "some-type"
    
    const q_id = await Excuse.findOne({ type: type })
    res.json(q_id)
```